# units of the quotient ring of the integers over a prime power $[{\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z]^*$ is cyclic multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers

I am studying Algebra as an extra curricular research project and in the reading I was assigned, the author somewhat offhandedly mentions that the units of  ${\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z$, which is to say $$({\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z)^*$$ forms a cyclic subgroup under the multiplication of  ${\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z$ fot an odd prime $P$ and a positive integer $e$.

The author also mentions that $({\Bbb Z}/2^e\Bbb Z)^*$, for $e$ an integer more than 3, is the direct product of a cyclic group of order 2 and a cyclic group of order $2^{(e-2)}$. The author refers to it as a "standard result" but I have not found much by researching it (I realize, likely because I am not using the right search terms, but I don't know what those would be. If anyone could give me an example of an appropriate search term to find the proof of the above, that would be equally appreciated) and what little I did find was well above my level.

I was able to show that the elements of $({\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z)^*$ are all the classes whose smallest positive representatives are coprime to $P^e$ and thus to find that the size of $({\Bbb Z}/P^e\Bbb Z)^*$ is $\Phi(P^e)=(P^{e-1})(P-1)$. I have not been able to show its cyclic nature.

Comment: Search on "primitive roots": this phrase refers to the generators of those cyclic groups (and their existence).

Comment: @paulgarret I am familiar with primitive roots and cyclic groups. What I am unable to find/prove is the proof of cyclic-ness for this particular group.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but "proof of existence of primitive roots..." should be in any elementary number theory text, and maybe on Wiki, and maybe somewhere on this site, too.

Comment: It is me who misunderstood. Thank you. My mind jumped over the connection between what you were saying and what I am looking for.